# Cookies are not saved in browser

Tags: go, nginx, cookies, cross-domain

I'm using gorilla session package to manage cookies but they are not saved in Browser.
Server and front end are running on different domains, so I think it is some CORS restrictions, because if I make a request from Postman or from the page served on the same domain as server, cookies are saving and all works well.

Also I use nginx to serve front end so maybe problem in lack of additional settings.
Here is code:

```
//settings for gorilla sessions
SessionStore = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte(SessionKey))
SessionStore.Options = &sessions.Options{
    Secure: true,
    Path:   "/",
}

//settings for cors issues. github.com/rs/cors package

    c := cors.New(cors.Options{
            AllowedOrigins:   []string{"https://clientdomain.com"},
            AllowCredentials: true,
        })

//simplified process of saving cookie. All returned errors are nil
func SignIn(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://clientdomain.com")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    session, err := SessionStore.Get(r, SessionName)
    err = session.Save(r, w)
}
```

And simple nginx configuration. Nginx works on docker and its all deployed on heroku. I tried this locally and everything worked so maybe it is an issue here, but I think it rather from CORS .

```
   server {
  listen $PORT default_server;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Browsers don't send any messages in console, they just don't save cookies.

Comment: Show the client code. The most likely reason is that [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) isn't enabled.

Comment: @ThinkGoodly yes, both server and client

Comment: @Peter I set withCredentials to true on requests

Comment: CORS doesn't affect cookies, only requests. If you were having a CORS issue, the requests would fail.

Comment: *"because if I make a request from Postman or from the page served on the same domain as server, cookies are saving and all works well."* - third party cookies (i.e. cookies not set from the origin of the current page) are often blocked by browsers by default today in order to defend against tracking.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can try with Firefox browser because it seems to be the only browser still allow 3rd party cookies so far.
Google Chrome 84+ is quite restrictive for cross-site cookie handling.

To make a 3rd party cookie working on modern browsers, It must satisfies 3 conditions:

- It is sent via the secure HTTPS protocol.
- It has `SameSite=None`
- Must set `Secure` flag

So, let's modify your backend a little bit:

```golang
SessionStore = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte(SessionKey))
SessionStore.Options = &sessions.Options{
    Path:     "/",
    Secure:   true,
    SameSite: http.SameSiteNoneMode,
}
```

On frontend, make sure your ajax request always go with `withCredentials`

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```